# Bluetooth 4.0 with older Bluetooth

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm trying to implement an application using a Bluetooth 4.0 module, and I wonder if using  this application with an Iphone 3GS containing a simple Bluetooth 2.1 EDR module is going to enable me take advantage of the the low energy in my 4.0 module.
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bluetooth 4.0 is the standard, which includes both classical Bluetooth Basic Rate/Enhanced Data Rate (BR/EDR) and Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE, or Bluetooth Smart, which is a marketing name).

Compatibility depends on the the device and Bluetooth chip e.g. is it a BR/EDR only chip (Bluetooth 3.0), a BLE only chip or a dual-mode chip capable of both BR/EDR and BLE. A dual-mode chip can (until 4.1, at least) only operates in either BR/EDR or BLE mode for any given connection.

A dual mode chip, certified as Bluetooth 4.0, can and should be able to connect to a Bluetooth 2.1 chip, in BR/EDR mode.

A Bluetooth BLE (Bluetooth Smart) chip will not be able to.

First, you must clearly determine if your Bluetooth 4.0 module is only capable of BLE.

Comment: I must also mention that when a BLE module is connected with a classical Bluetooth module, we lose all advantage of low energy, so if you want to use a Bluetooth 4.0 with another Bluetooth 2.1 EDR for example, you won't have any advantage it's just like you are using 2.1 EDR in both. BLE is only useful when communicating with another BLE device.

Comment: This is not proper, A first of all, A BLE module can not connect to BR/EDR module. if a BLE module is connected to a BR/EDR+BLE device(ie a dual mode device)it doesn't mean all advantage of BLE module is lost. Sensors can be made using BLE technology and it can be connected to a Dual mode device. Still the sensor have all advantage of a BLE device and it can work on a coin cell battery. eg: A heartbeat monitor with BLE is connected to Mobile phone support dual mode and an application in mobile phone records the heartbeat rate.

Comment: I must recognize that I can't see how a BLE sensor could consume fewer energy if it uses old Bluetooth stack ( 2.1 EDR for example) using a permanent link, and handshaking

Answer (score 8):

According to Bluetooth 4.0 (ie BLE), there are two kinds of devices
1) A dual mode device , which support BR/EDR , ie Bluetooth 2.1 or 3.0  and same time it support Bluetooth 4.0
2) A BLE only device, which supports only Bluetooth 4.0

In general, sensors which supposed to be work in coin cell battery will be designed with BLE chipset and mobile devices will be designed with Dual mode chipset. So the mobile device can have interoperability with other BR/EDR device as well as it can connect and fetch data from sensors.

More over a BLE device can not communicate with a classic Bluetooth device[ BR/EDR or Bluetooth 2.1 device]

Answer (score 3):

No of coures not, how can a Bluetooth 2.1 magically turn into a bluetooth 4 module.

If you apps requires Bluetooth 4.0 than add it to the `Required device capabilities` in the `info.plist`. Add `bluetooth-le` to the `Required device capabilities`.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth 4.0 in low energy mode is actually quite different from what people consider classical Bluetooth. While Bluetooth 4.0 in the iPhone is backwards compatible with Bluetooth 2.1, Bluetooth low energy in general (or Bluetooth Smart as it is also known) is not backwards compatible.

Comment: This is totally wrong. BLE is the same as Bluetooth 4.0, so none of the terms are backwards compatible with regular Bluetooth

Comment: That's wrong. You can have dual-chipset supporting Bluetooth AND BLE, but you cannot integrate them into one. The functionality is completely different, the modulation index is different, the access protocol is different.

Comment: What is wrong, the comment or the post? I know you can have dual chipsets, but that doesn't change the case one bit

Answer (score 0):

The corebluetooth framework specifies functionality with Bluetooth low energy (4.0) and is only available with newer iPads and iPhone 4S.

You cannot by any means work with Bluetooth 4.0 devices using an older iOS device.

Comment: Not really. It's available on many phones, including HTC One, Galaxy S3 and Motorola Droid. I have tested on Motorla Droid and it works fine :) They even have a  good API with documentation.

Comment: well, try developing for S3 and make it and you get a one up ;) I actually forgot to mention the droid and razr

Comment: Haven't tried others than Droid and iPhone, but I saw that they have BLE chipset inside. I believe you are right and maybe they are not functionally supported.

Answer (score 0):

- Bluetooth Low energy only chip cannot communicate with Classic BR/EDR Chips.
- 4.0 Bluetooth specification is an umbrella specification that contains both BLE and BR/EDR.
- A Dual Mode chip contains BLE as well as BR/EDR capability. Of course, Host also should be capable of dual mode strictly speaking. Dual mode chips, obviously can communicate with both kinds of chips.